# Forge Model Derivative Trying to get object properties by externalId fails but works with objectID

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Using this Model Derivative [endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) we want to retrieve the properties of an object by calling it with its externalId. We follow the procedure explainined [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-objectid-query-parameter-model-derivative-properties-api).

The endpoint works using the objectid, in this case 3:

```
    "data": {
        "type": "properties",
        "collection": [
            {
                "objectid": 3,
                "name": "Finished Ceiling Height",
                "externalId": "5d365ed4-cccc-4589-b4e1-a8c5c744672a-0046dd63",
                "properties": {
                    "General": {
                        "Override": ""
                    },
                    "Extents": {
                        "Scope Box": "None"
                    },
                    "Constraints": {
                        "Elevation": "8.667 ft-and-fractional-in",
                        "Story Above": "Default"
                    },
                    "Dimensions": {
                        "Computation Height": "3.000 ft-and-fractional-in"
                    },
                    "Identity Data": {
                        "Name": "Finished Ceiling Height",
                        "Structural": "No",
                        "Building Story": "Yes",
                        "Asset ID": "",
                        "Asset Location": "",
                        "Asset Category": "",
                        "Workset": "Shared Views, Levels, Grids",
                        "Edited by": ""
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The documentation states that we could also use externalId to get the same result.

> The objectid of an object can change if the design is translated to SVF or SVF2 again. If you require a persistent ID to reference an object, use externalId.

But changing objectid=**3** to objectid=**5d365ed4-cccc-4589-b4e1-a8c5c744672a-0046dd63** returns an error 400:

```
{
    "diagnostic": "Invalid 'objectid' parameter"
}
```

We also tried to convert the GUID to base64, use externalid instead of objectid as the parameter name. Everything with the same results.

Any ideas? Are we missunderstanding the documentation?

**Note:** Accesing the viewer is not an option at the moment, neither downloading the sqlite/json files

**[Edit 1]**
We tried setting the query parameter as externalId/externalid receiving the same results.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/urn/metadata/guid/properties?externalId=43f2c4e0-d09b-4151-a349-1b6f684411c6-004c8717' \
--header 'x-ads-force: true' \
--header 'x-ads-derivative-format: fallback' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objectId parameter accepts numerical values only. As you can see from the API response, objectId is a numerical value. You cannot pass a string to this parameter, unfortunately.

However, our engineering team is working on the new property API which supports more filters. You might be interested in the new property metadata API mentioned in https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Forge-Road-Map-2021 at 20 mins.

Comment: I understand, but the documentation is misleading. Could we request to clarify it a little?

Comment: Could you kindly point out where it caused the misleading? From the [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-objectid-query-parameter-model-derivative-properties-api) and [API doc](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/#query-string-parameters), I can see they all use a numerical example.

Comment: Sure @eason_kang! For me, the quote below implies that objectId and externalId are exchangable for the endpoint. If externalId is not compatible with the endpoint, why mentioning it there? 




**"The objectid of an object can change if the design is translated to SVF or SVF2 again. If you require a persistent ID to reference an object, use externalId."**

The use of the long on the description of the parameter was clear on hindsight.

Comment: Hi @PabloD., as I know, our engineering team is following the terminology similar to https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering, so `?objectid=123` means that please find properties where `objectid is 123`, it won't find that on other fields. So, if you want to search properties by externalId, then the querying string would be `?externalId=xxxx`, not `?objectid=xxxx`

Comment: The new API I mentioned will support filtering by other fields like `externalId`.